# How to auto delete ObjectId referances in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

im trying to auto delete notifications referance from users ,when notification gets deleted

the userSchema looks like

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 
  notifications: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Notification",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The notification model looks like this

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
notificationSchema.pre("deleteOne", function (next) {
  this.model("User").deleteOne({ notifications: this._id }, next);
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Notification", notificationSchema);
```

when i try to delete notification i get an error ,which looks like

```
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got User
```

also is there a way to auto delete it [referances of notification in user] using TTL for notifications

Answer (score 0):

ok ,after a few try and error. I came up with this solution..

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
notificationSchema.pre("deleteOne", function (next) {
  let id = this.getQuery()["_id"];
  mongoose.model("User").findOne(
    {
      notifications: id,
    },
    (err, res) => {
      const index = res.notifications.findIndex((x) => x._id == id);
      res.notifications.splice(index, 1);
      res.save();
      next();
    }
  );
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Notification", notificationSchema);
```

Can i make any improvements ?